# Can't remove duplicate cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-translate

I created a custom UI for the google translate javascript plugin by adding some buttons and then setting the `googtrans` cookie when the user selects a language.  This works totally fine locally.  However I noticed when I put it on a live site, the cookie gets set and then a duplicate cookie appears that overrides the one that I've set.

[Duplicate Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f8UL.png)

The mystery cookie seems to be the domain with a dot prepended to it.  I've tried adding the dot to my cookie's domain, but that doesn't work and according to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes), that dot will be ignored anyway.

I've tried just clearing the cookie manually through the Chrome console

```
document.cookie = "googtrans=; expires=" + new Date + "; domain=.domain.org; path=/";
```

and that does clear the cookie that I set, but leaves the duplicate cookie unchanged.

Anyone know a way of nuking all of the possible cookies or something?  It's so strange that it only does this on a live site.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I randomly figured it out right after posting this.  If I set two cookies, one WITH and domain and one WITHOUT, the one without a domain will write to the `.domain.org` cookie.

```
document.cookie = "googtrans=;" + new Date + ";path=/;domain=domain.org";
document.cookie = "googtrans=;" + new Date + ";path=/;";
```

I don't know why, because the documentation says that NOT specifying a domain means that subdomains are NOT included, which is what the dot prefix was originally for.